# App crashes with firebase_analytics in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

When I use dependencies:
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.6, app crashes in Android simulator. How can I solve this problem? No error shown, just crash. Other flutterFire plugin works well.

This is the log of Android studio. Installing never ends.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter clean` and make another attempt at running the simulator. 
I'd try reinstalling the dependencies and check to see that you're on the latest versions.

Comment: What other methods have you tried?

Have you tried cold booting the AVD?

Comment: downgrading the plugin, yes I just tried cold boot. but not worked

Comment: Go to the Gradle Project for your project and run 'sync gradle project'. Hopefully that correctly sets all your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded the plugin to 5.0.11 and it worked.

`firebase_analytics: ^5.0.11`